# Finding Coordinations of obstacles in a grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm doing Mars Rover kata challenge. I have already finished programming the robot to go around 10x10 grid and to stop when encountering the boundaries.

I am now programming the robot to stop when it encounters the obstacles and report that it encountered the obstacles. I've created the two-dimensional array called `testBoard`. I can easily add or change the obstacles around. I'm trying to program a function called `obstacles` to push the coordinations to `obstaclesList` array so that I can program the robot to test its new position against the obstacles' coordinations.

```
let testBoard = [ 
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,"Bottle",null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,"Rock",null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"Statue",null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
];
let obstaclesList = [];

function obstacles(testBoard) {
  for(let i = 0; i < testBoard.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < testBoard[i].length; j++) {
      if(testBoard[i][j] !== null) {
        obstaclesList.push("x:" + i + " y:" + j);
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(obstaclesList);
```

However, I am unable to gather the coordinations in the `obstaclesList` array. Can you let me know what's wrong, please?

Here is my full code at [Mars Rover kata - IronHack Pre-work Exercise](https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/PMaoYO)

I'll put my full code here:

```js
// Rover Object Goes Here
// ======================
let roverMars = {
  direction: "N",
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  travelLog: ["x:0 y:0"]
};

let testBoard = [ 
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,"Bottle",null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,"Rock",null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"Statue",null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
  [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
];
let obstaclesList = [];

function obstacles(testBoard) {
  for(let i = 0; i < testBoard.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < testBoard[i].length; j++) {
      if(testBoard[i][j] !== null) {
        obstaclesList.push("x:" + i + " y:" + j);
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(obstaclesList);

// ======================
function turnLeft(rover){
  console.log("turnLeft was called!");
  switch(rover.direction) {
    case "N": rover.direction = "W";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
    case "W": rover.direction = "S";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
    case "S": rover.direction = "E";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
    case "E": rover.direction = "N";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
  }
}

function turnRight(rover){
  console.log("turnRight was called!");
  switch(rover.direction) {
    case "N": rover.direction = "E";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
    case "W": rover.direction = "N";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
    case "S": rover.direction = "W";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
    case "E": rover.direction = "S";
      console.log("Rover is now facing " + rover.direction);
      break;
  }
}

function moveForward(rover){
  console.log("moveForward was called");
  
  switch(rover.direction) {
    case "N": if(rover.y <= 0) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else {
      rover.y--;
      console.log("Rover moved up. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);                           
  }
      break;
    case "W": if(rover.x <= 0) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else {
      rover.x--;
      console.log("Rover moved left. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);
  }
      break;
    case "S": if(rover.y >= 10) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else {
      rover.y++;
      console.log("Rover moved down. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);
  }
      break;
    case "E": if(rover.x >= 10) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else {
      rover.x++;
      console.log("Rover moved right. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);         
  }
      break;
  }
  roverMars.travelLog.push("x:" + rover.x + " y:" + rover.y);
}

function moveBackward(rover){
  console.log("moveBackward was called");
  
  switch(rover.direction) {
    case "N": if(rover.y >= 10) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else {
      rover.y++;
      console.log("Rover moved down. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);                           
  }
      break;
    case "W": if(rover.x >= 10) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else {
      rover.x++;
      console.log("Rover moved right. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);
  }
      break;
    case "S": if(rover.y <= 0) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else {
      rover.y--;
      console.log("Rover moved up. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);
  }
      break;
    case "E": if(rover.x <= 0) { 
      console.log("You can't place the rover outside of the 10x10 grid!");
      } else {
      rover.x--;
      console.log("Rover moved left. The position is now " + rover.x + ", " + rover.y);         
  }
      break;
  }
  roverMars.travelLog.push("x:" + rover.x + " y:" + rover.y);
}

function commandments(roverlist) {
  let passRegex = /[lrfb]/g;
  var passResult = roverlist.match(passRegex);
  for(let i = 0; i < passResult.length; i++) {
    switch(roverlist[i]) {
      case "l": turnLeft(roverMars);
        break;
      case "r": turnRight(roverMars);
        break;
      case "f": moveForward(roverMars);
        break;
      case "b": moveBackward(roverMars);
        break;
    }
  }
  //console.log("passResult: " + passResult);
}
//commandments("bbzbzy");
//turnLeft(roverMars);
//turnRight(roverMars);
//moveForward(roverMars);
//console.log(roverMars.travelLog);
```

Comment: `function obstacles` populates `obstaclesList `, but you never call it.

Comment: ?? what?? I'm not asking the function to add the obstacles. I'm asking the function to find the obstacles and add for example: [x: 4, y: 7], which is the obstacle's location (coordinations) to the array.

Comment: Your `obstaclesList` array starts as empty. You've written a function called `obstacles` that *would* add the items to it, ***but you never call it***. Therefore, nothing is ever added to `obstaclesList`. I'm not understanding the confusion to be quite honest.

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry, I fixed it now to call it. I got my thinking mixed up, trying to call the testBoard in the function parameter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are not calling you function. You just declared it. Before your `console.log(obstaclesList)` try to invoke the function like:

```
obstacles(testBoard);
console.log(obstaclesList);
```

[image]

And if you can try to change the name of the either parameter testBoard in obstacles function or the variable with the same name, cuz it can confuse you. :)